# How can I loop a turtle.write statement?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I currently have a grid and need to display numbers for each square,
How can I loop the following to have 1,2,3 and so on at different locations.
They will firstly need to move east 4 places then begin at the second set of squares above.

```
for a in range (10):

    turtle.write("1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this and to my understanding that is what you want:

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
for a in range(10):
     t.fd(#you need to write the number of pixels to move here)
     t.write(a)
```

Please next time try to explain more ,show more code or the grid ,its hard to understand what you want.
If this isn't what you looked for please tell me more!